# Custom script is not being run by systemd before suspend

Tags: systemd

I'm placing a script to `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` and suspending system with `pm-suspend` command. However, my custom script is not being run. Here is the script properties:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 833 Jan  2 13:13 /lib/systemd/system-sleep/scrub-supervisor.sh
```

I also tried to create a systemd service file with the following content:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/check-disk-health-supervisor.service 
[Unit]
Description=Pause running btrfs scrubs on suspend
Before=suspend.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/ceremcem/.sbin/erik-sync/scrub/scrub-supervisor.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

```
$ sudo systemctl status check-disk-health-supervisor
● check-disk-health-supervisor.service - Pause running btrfs scrubs on suspend
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/check-disk-health-supervisor.service; ena
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

This didn't work either. How do we debug in such cases?

Comment: Do you need `Type=forking`?